# Authenticate user without login post call

Tags: spring-boot

So currently I setup a simple token system to require account confirmation. Now upon confirming the token I'd like to automatically authenticate the user.
I am a bit lost were to start with this.I've been searching on the internet, but it seems like every solution is using the login call.

I would like to **not** use the built in post call. If there is no other solution I could of course just call a small javascript post call.

Were would I have to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpServletRequest login() method to force authentication after the registration finishes. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-auto-login-user-after-registration) is a nice blog about how to do that

Following is the snippet from the blog

```
public void authWithHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String username, String password) {
        try {
            request.login(username, password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while login ", e);
        }
}
```